# Kohana 3.3 expanding the Auth module

Tags: authentication, kohana, multi-user

I'm building an application using the Auth module for which I need at least 3 account types : Employer, Employee and Client. Since these accounts have different properties, functions and relationships (ex: employers has_many employees) I guess I need to have them on 3 separate ORM models.

The method I thought was to tweak the Auth module to replace the 'User' model with the appropriate sub-model (employer, employee, client), corresponding the the user type in the database.

Can this be done, or is it bad practice?

Comment: Use the same user table for all users and have connecting tables for Employer, Employee, and Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such rurposes you need to create different Model classes for each account type extending default Auth_ORM's `Model_User` class.

Then you need to create new `Auth_ORM` class extending `Kohana_Auth_ORM` class in your `application/classes` folder.

In this file you need to rewrite `protected _login()` method, so its `$user` variable to point to required account type.

Comment: But with this you would either have various tables in your database for the users which would lead to problems with the fk constraint in `roles_users` or you would have unused/unwanted rows if you share one table. Also wouldn't it make more sense to have individual classes for roles instead of users?

Comment: Probably it is. The question is: would roles be required in such a case? I'd not use roles in  my example. Every account type would be a role itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found interesting repository here: https://github.com/alexgisby/MAuth.
I have the same problem as You have, so maybe if You manage to resolve it You could share the solution. I think the repository from this link could be a solution, but i didn't manage to implement it so far

Answer (score 0):

You can have 1 model - User and 3 different roles. And depending to role, you can load specific module, which will contain required classes.

For example, if User has role Employee you will load modules/role_employee