# kohana auth module with multiple user types

Tags: database, authentication, kohana

Is there any way to use Auth module in Kohana work with three different users tables? Or maybe is better to have one user table 'users' and have different profiles tables for theese three kind of users? The problem is that different users have to vave completely different fields in table, also authentification needs to be done on different criteria (fields). Please advice how to model such a scenario.

Comment: There is already a similar unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714047/kohana-3-3-expanding-the-auth-module

Answer (score 0):

(kingkero is right) You should extend Kohana_Auth or Kohana_Auth_ORM for that and override the methods to do what you need..